# RuntimeBeanNameReference vs RuntimeBeanReference

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I was wondering what is difference between those two? `RuntimeBeanReference` worked for me rather `RuntimeBeanNameReference` for the following scenario:

```
    GenericBeanDefinition bd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    bd.setBeanClassName(beanClassName);
    MutablePropertyValues pvs = new MutablePropertyValues();
    pvs.add("dataSource", new RuntimeBeanReference(dataSourceBeanName));
    bd.setPropertyValues(pvs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RuntimeBeanReference` correctly. The code you posted is basically what Spring generates when you have

```
<bean class="beanClassName">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBeanName" />
</bean>
```

At run time, Spring will find the bean referenced by `dataSourceBeanName` and inject it.

`RuntimeBeanNameReference`, as far as I can tell (there are **very** few uses of it), is basically used to inject the bean name while validating that a bean with that name exists in the context.